# How do I convert UNIX path to DOS path

Tags: perl, unix, dos

Need a regex or some other method to convert UNIX path to DOS path.

I have

```
C:/My Document/Photo.gif
```

Need

```
C:\My Document\Photo.gif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the regular expression

```
s/\//\\/g
```

Comment: This did not work for me, but Jonathan Leffler's version did, using { and } as separators.

Comment: @WarrenP , works well:
`$ echo "C:/My Document/Photo.gif" | sed 's/\//\\/g'` produces 
`C:\My Document\Photo.gif`

Answer (score 9):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use File::Spec::Win32;

print File::Spec::Win32->canonpath('C:/My Document/Photo.gif'), "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, you do not normally need to do that mapping unless you are going to invoke something via `cmd.exe`; the Windows API is perfectly happy with slashes instead of backslashes in file names (but `cmd.exe` insists that slash starts an option).

Then, the direct answer to your question is perhaps:

```
my $file = "C:/My Documents/Photo.gif";
$file =~ s{/}{\\}g;
print "$file\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `/` with `\`. Though I must point out that you can use forward-slashes in Windows.

Comment: You mean like find & replace? :)

Answer (score -1):

A bit superfluous, but you could use tr instead of a regex:

```
tr!\\!/!;
```